# Extend EventEmitter and call emit

Tags: typescript, eventemitter

I tried this in TypeScript:

```js
import events from 'events'
import EventEmitter from 'events'

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  condition: boolean
  emit() {
    if (this.condition) {
      return events.EventEmitter.prototype.emit.apply(this, arguments)
    }
  }
}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter()
myEmitter.emit('something')
```

This results in `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)` in the last line (when calling `emit('something')`.

How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are passing one argument to `emit`, which declares zero parameters.

There is another problem. The signature of `emit` in `EventEmitter` is:

```js
emit(event: string | symbol, ...args: any[]): boolean
```

If you want to override the method in a derived class, the signature of the overridden method must be compatible with that of the base class method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it that way:

```js
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  condition: boolean
  emit(event: string, ...args: any[] {
    if (this.condition) {
      return events.EventEmitter.prototype.emit(event, ...args)
    }
  }
}
```